# AWS SAM CLI Local Start API - Bind/Expose to port 443

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

In AWS SAM CLI in local start-api there is port option where you can bind to a specific port. Sam will provide a url (http://127.0.0.1:3000) when you set for example to -port 3000.

But how do you bind to port 443 so you can access your url via "https"?

Here is a sample command:

```
sam local start-api --debug --env-vars env.json --host local.lambda.com -p 443 --skip_pull_image --docker_network=services_app-network --warm_containers=EAGER
```

Output:
I get a permission denied error when binding to port 443
[image]

Any Ideas how to make this work?